# can not get correct x and y locations

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

my app is mfc CDialog based. CImageView is inherited from CScrollView. my images are 1600x 1000. my client area is smaller than image size. I like to get the pixel coordinate that I left click on or move mouse on.

```
void CImageView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint pt)
{
CString s;
s.Format("%d %d", pt.x,pt.y);
AfxMessageBox(s);
}
```

If I scroll the vertical and horizontal bars all the way to the bottom and right respectively,
i can view the pixel in most bottom right corner but its coordinate (x,y) is not correct, it is smaller than the 1600x1000. How can i get the correct pixel coordinate if scroll bars are moved?.  It seems as the scroll bars get moved, the 1,1 pixel location moves as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetScrollPosition` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dshkctc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to retrieve the xy coordinates of the top left of the client area according to the scroll bar positions, then add the xy offset you get from the mouse click.

```cpp
void CImageView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint pt)
{
    CPoint ptImage = GetScrollPosition() + pt;
    CString s;
    s.Format("%d %d", ptImage.x, ptImage.y);
    AfxMessageBox(s);
}
```